# WCF TCP Secured customBinding: There was no channel that could accept the message

Tags: c#, wcf, security, tcp

We are using **custom binding** with **TCP** and **Secured using Certificate**.
The WCF servers are behind a Load balancing server.

We get the following exception on the host servers.

**There was no channel that could accept the message with action '{MethodName}'**.

On the client side we get these exceptions

1. Security processor was unable to find a security header in the
   message. This might be because the message is an unsecured fault or
   because there is a binding mismatch between the communicating
   parties.   This can occur if the service is configured for security
   and the client is not using security.
2. The communication object,    System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionClientSettings`1+ClientSecurityDuplexSessionChannel[System.ServiceModel.Channels.IDuplexSessionChannel],
   cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state.
3. The server did not provide a meaningful reply; this might be caused
   by a contract mismatch, a premature session shutdown or an internal
   server error.
4. An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party. See the inner FaultException for the fault code and detail.
5. An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

**Here is the binding on the client side**

```
<binding name="CustomBinding" closeTimeout="00:02:00" openTimeout="00:02:00"                                  sendTimeout="00:02:00">
  <transactionFlow/>
  <security authenticationMode="SecureConversation" requireSecurityContextCancellation="true">
    <secureConversationBootstrap authenticationMode="CertificateOverTransport"/>
  </security>
  <binaryMessageEncoding compressionFormat="GZip" />
  <sslStreamSecurity requireClientCertificate="true"/>
  <tcpTransport maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647">
    <connectionPoolSettings groupName="GN" />
  </tcpTransport>
</binding
```

**Here is the server side binding**

```
<binding name="CustomBinding" receiveTimeout="00:02:00" sendTimeout="00:02:00">
      <transactionFlow/>
      <security authenticationMode="SecureConversation" requireSecurityContextCancellation="true">
        <secureConversationBootstrap authenticationMode="CertificateOverTransport"/>
      </security>
      <binaryMessageEncoding compressionFormat="GZip" />
      <sslStreamSecurity requireClientCertificate="true"/>
      <tcpTransport maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647">
        <connectionPoolSettings maxOutboundConnectionsPerEndpoint="500" />
      </tcpTransport>
    </binding>
```

**Here is the end point behavior**

```
<endpointBehaviors>          
    <behavior name="CustomBehavior">
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646"/>
      <clientCredentials>
        <clientCertificate findValue="" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" storeLocation="LocalMachine" />
        <serviceCertificate>
          <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerOrChainTrust"/>
        </serviceCertificate>
      </clientCredentials>
    </behavior>     
  </endpointBehaviors>
```

**Here is the service behavior**

```
<behavior name="CustCertBehavior">
      <serviceCredentials>
        <serviceCertificate findValue="" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" storeLocation="LocalMachine" />
        <clientCertificate>
          <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerOrChainTrust" />
        </clientCertificate>
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: Why do you use custom binding, not the NetTcp one?

Comment: We are using it as it provides us the ability to customize further.

Comment: I don't know the exact reason, because custom binding is more complicated in its implementation. But I know that according to the Microsoft recommendations we have to use predefined bindings whenever possible. That is why I would try to start from implementing the NetTcpBinding, because it contains all the functionality you have in your custom binding. It would be much easier to understand what is wrong

Comment: The main reason was to set
<binaryMessageEncoding compressionFormat="GZip" />